# Is there a difference between anti-anxiety and anti-depression drugs?

Tags: medications, side-effects, antidepressants, benzodiazepines, anti-anxiety-meds

I've recently come across two terms "Anxiolytic drugs" and "Anti-depressant drugs". I wanted to know how they differ from each other; *if* they do.

I mean, sure, "anxiety" isn't the same as "depression" but do the *effects* of these drugs differ widely (so much, that they're classified under different names)?

For example, Chlorodiazepoxide is classified as an anxiolytic drug, while Phenelzine is classified as an anti-depressant. Say I had a patient **A** who's been prescribed Chlorodiazepoxide; patient **B** has been prescribed Phenelzine by a different physician. Barring possible allergic reactions, or some kind of known sensitivity to either drug, could they possibly take *each other's* medication and hope for more or less, the same effect? As in; **A** takes Phenelzine, but **B** takes Chlorodiazepoxide. [I just cooked up that example, only to see the difference between the two classes of drugs]

I'm still in High School, so if my question seems a little naive, apologies.